# Launch jQuery .datepicker from Another JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to launch .datepicker only if the text entered into a field does not meet a set of criteria.  But, I can not figure out how to launch .datepicker other than directly from a field getting focus or a button being presses.

What I'm trying to do...

The HTML

```
<input type="text" id="userDate" name="userDate" style="width: 100px;" onblur="checkDate(this.id);" />
```

The JS

```
function checkDate(theId)
{
    var enteredValue = document.getElementById(theId).value;
    var checkedValue = evaluateValue(enteredValue); // this checks to see if the text meets the criteria

    if (checkedValue == null)
    {
        // this is where I want to call the .datepicker to have the calendar show up
        $("#userDate").datepicker();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(theId).value = checkedValue;
    }
}
```

I know, this would be easier if the calendar just came up when the text field gets focus.  But, this is not the way the client wants it to work.  They want to accept user input as long as it falls into their desired formats.  If not, then they want the calendar and a default, forced format.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd advise binding the onblur event in jquery aswell. instead of in html.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the datepicker in jQuery UI, you would show the datepicker like this:

```
$("#userDate").datepicker("show");
```

**Edit:**

Your code would probably have to look something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#userDate").datepicker(); // <-- Create the datepicker on load
});

function checkDate(theId)
{
    var enteredValue = document.getElementById(theId).value;
    var checkedValue = evaluateValue(enteredValue); // this checks to see if the text meets the criteria

    if (checkedValue == null)
    {
        // this is where I want to call the .datepicker to have the calendar show up
        $("#userDate").datepicker("show");  // <-- Show datepicker when needed
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(theId).value = checkedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the above code, I get a message in the error console that says, "a is undefined in (http://ajax.googleapis.com/...)"

Comment: @user1084262 See my update answer, you probably need to create the datepicker on load.

Comment: I tried that already.  The problem with that is when the text field first gets focus, the calendar pops up.  I need a way to suppress that.  I also tried initializing the datepicker as disabled, but that disabled the input field as well, not just the popup calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after many cans of Pepsi Max and even more hours of research, trial and error; this is what I've come up with... and it meets my needs.

```
$(document).ready( function()
    {
        $("#userDate").blur(function()
        {
            var convertResults = convertMyDate('userDate'); // call to my code that checks the date for accepted formats

            if (convertResults == null)
            {
                $("#userDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
                $("#userDate").datepicker("show");
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('userDate').value = convertResults.toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
            }
        });
    });
```

The only problem now is that the client's form has 14 date fields.  So... copy this 13 more times in my code!?  I just don't have the time right now to figure out a way to roll all this into a single function that will initiate all of them in a loop...

Any suggestions on that would be appreciated.